# VF Component: Wrong type for attribute. Expected <someType>, found String

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

Simple use case of passing a parent controller's instance to a custom VF component's attribute to allow for inter-controller communication

**Component**

```
<apex:component id="SomeComponent">
    <apex:attribute name="controller" type="SomeParentController" description="the parent (calling) controller"/>
</apex:component>
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page id="SomeVF" controller="SomeParentController">
    <c:SomeComponent controller="{!this}"/>
</apex:page>
```

**Main VF Controller**

```
public with sharing class SomeParentController {
    public SomeParentController getThis() {return this;}
}
```

When compiling the VF page - get this error on the line `c:SomeComponent ...` :

> Wrong type for attribute . Expected SomeParentController, found String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(An hour of my life lost on this one ..hopefully, this will aid someone else..)*

You can't name a VF's component attribute with `name="controller"`

The VF page compiler gets confused, it knows the component's attribute type is `SomeParentController` but at the same time it is expecting when encountering the presence of an attribute `controller=...` to look like what you would expect in `apex:page controller="aStringThatIsAControllerName"`

You can resolve the problem by using an attribute name other than `controller`

**Component**

```
<apex:component id="SomeComponent">
    <apex:attribute name="somethingOtherThanLiterallyController" type="SomeParentController" description="the parent (calling) controller"/>
</apex:component>
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page id="SomeVF" controller="SomeParentController">
    <c:SomeComponent somethingOtherThanLiterallyController="{!this}"/>
</apex:page>
```